# how to initialize i18next

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, i18next

I want to create an multi language app via `i18next` package

But the package does not work correctly
here is `i18next` file

```
import i18n from "i18next";
import Backend from "i18next-xhr-backend";
import LanguageDetector from "i18next-browser-languagedetector";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";
const fallbackLng = ["en"];
const availableLanguages = ["de", "en", "fr", "it"];
i18n
  .use(Backend).use(LanguageDetector).use(initReactI18next).init({
    fallbackLng, 
    debug: true,
    whitelist: availableLanguages,
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false,
    },
  });

export default i18n;
```

here is how i created the folders for `JSON` files

[image]

this is how JSON files are written

```
{
  "select": {
    "1": "choisissez votre langue"
  }
}
```

and here is how i tried to use it

```
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  {t("select.1")}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your json missing the translation key work like this:

```
translation: {"select": "My translation", "nextOne": "Another Translation"}
```

My fully work example (in real project):

```
import i18n from "i18next";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";

import locales from "./locales";
import { getLang } from "../helpers/language-helper";

i18n
  .use(initReactI18next) // passes i18n down to react-i18next
  .init({
    resources: locales,
    lng: getLang(),
    fallbackLng: getLang(),
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false,
    },
  });
```

// Locales file:

```
import en from "./en";
import ko from "./ko";
import ar from "./ar";

export default {
  en,
  ko,
  ar,
};
```

// Translation files (en for example):

```
export default {
  translation: {
    language: "EN",
    kaitTitle: "Kait Solution",
commonValiation: {
      htmlTagMessasge: "Html tags not allowed",
      tryAgain: 'Something went wrong. Please try again',
      requiredField: "This field is Required",
    },
}
}
```

// Use

```
t('commonValiation.htmlTagMessasge')
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like the problem was about importing i18next in the `index` file, I will try this way later on...